# Having trouble when initializing Input layer with constant value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have three Input layers in my model, and 'input3' is set as constant value. Then I input 'input3' to Embedding layer , get the result 'lookup_table' and then do some other operations.

But when I use model.summary() to observe my model and the training parameters, I find that the Input3 layer and the Embedding layer are not added to the model, and I think the parameters of Embedding layer will not be trained.

I am really troubled with that, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
The code 

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import*
import keras.backend as K


np_constant = np.array([[1,2,3],
                        [4,5,6],
                        [7,8,9]])

def NN():
    input1 = Input(batch_shape=(None,1),name='input1',dtype='int32')
    input2 = Input(batch_shape=(None,1),name='input2',dtype='int32')
    # constant_tensor = K.constant(np_constant)
    input3 = Input(tensor=K.constant(np_constant),batch_shape=(3,3),dtype='int32',name='constant_input_3')
    embedding = Embedding(input_dim=10,output_dim=5,input_length=3)
    lookup_table = embedding(input3)
    lookup_table = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1,15)))(lookup_table)

    output1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(lookup_table, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(input1)
    output2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(lookup_table, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(input2)

    # Merge branches
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)([output1, output2])
    # Process merged branch
    output = Dense(units=2
                   , activation='softmax'
                   )(output)

    model = Model([input1, input2, input3], outputs=output)
    return model

model = NN()
model.summary()
in_1 = np.array([1,2,1])
in_2 = np.array([1,0,1])
model.compile()  # just for example
model.fit([in_1,in_2])
```

```
The model summary

Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input2 (InputLayer)             (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 1, 15)        0           input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 1, 15)        0           input2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 2, 15)        0           lambda_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 2, 2)         32          concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 32
Trainable params: 32
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I have to feed data in the model.fit() function, and the input3 is always constant and the shape of input3 is different from input1 and input2, so I use it in this way. But I have no idea why the Input3 layer and Embedding layer are not added to the model.

Comment: `input3` and `Embedding` are not in the graph because you did not connect them to any subsequent layers. If you look into your code, it's apparent that the output `lookup_table` has not been used by any following layer in the graph. You have to somehow connect it to the `output` layer of the graph.

Comment: You have to figure out what you need to do with the `lookup_table` and that determines how you should use it in the architecture.

Comment: @Anakin Thanks for your answer. In fact, I use `lookup_table` in the following Lamba layer, `output1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(lookup_table, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(input1)` . I use K.gather function to look up in the `lookup_table` according to `input1` and `input2`, then get `output1` and `output2`.  The `output1` and `output2` are related with the final output.

Comment: Okay, yeah I missed that. Sorry

Comment: Okay, I think this is because the `Lambda` layer only gets one input tensor `input1` or `input2`. The `lookup_table` tensor is not considered as an input. maybe you can write a custom layer that takes in 2 input tensors and do the same gather operation inside. I think that might work for your case.

Comment: Actually you can also pass a list of tensors into a `Lambda`. That might be the easy way out.

Comment: @Anakin Sorry for that, I am not very clear about 'pass a list of tensors into a `Lambda`' . Could you give an example? Thanks very much.

Comment: This is an example code that I found online https://gist.github.com/akshaychawla/02849170e190fbd7fa9d431450e8d6ef

Comment: @Anakin  Sorry for replying so late, a little busy this week. Thanks for your patient explanation and the example code you provided works fine. I will show the modified code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify my original code, I define a custom function outside the model and pass a list of tensors into a `Lambda` layer as Anakin suggested. Here is the modified codes.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import*
import keras.backend as K


np_constant = np.array([[1,2,3],
                        [4,5,6],
                        [7,8,9]])

def look_up(arg):
    in1 = arg[0]
    in2 = arg[1]
    lookup_table = arg[2]

    in1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1, )))(in1)
    in2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1, )))(in2)

    output1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(lookup_table, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(in1)
    output2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(lookup_table, K.cast(x, dtype='int32')))(in2)
    return [output1,output2]

def NN():
    input1 = Input(batch_shape=(None,1),name='input1',dtype='int32')
    input2 = Input(batch_shape=(None,1),name='input2',dtype='int32')
    # constant_tensor = K.constant(np_constant)
    input3 = Input(tensor=K.constant(np_constant),batch_shape=(3,3),dtype='int32',name='constant_input_3')
    lookup_table = Embedding(input_dim=10,output_dim=5,input_length=3)(input3)
    lookup_table = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1, 15)))(lookup_table)


    output1 = Lambda(look_up)([input1,input2,lookup_table])[0]
    output2 = Lambda(look_up)([input1,input2,lookup_table])[1]
    # Merge branches
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)([output1, output2])
    # Process merged branch
    output = Dense(units=2
                   , activation='softmax'
                   )(output)

    model = Model([input1, input2, input3], outputs=output)
    return model

model = NN()
model.summary()
input_1 = np.array([1,2,1])
input_2 = np.array([1,0,1])
model.compile()  # just for example
model.fit([input_1,input_2])
```

In this way, the `Embedding` could be added to the model. And `input3` is a constant tensor, we don't need to feed it in model.fit() function.

```
The model summary

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
constant_input_3 (InputLayer)   (3, 3)               0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (3, 3, 5)            50          constant_input_3[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input2 (InputLayer)             (None, 1)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (3, 15)              0           embedding_1[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               [(None, 15), (None,  0           input1[0][0]                     
                                                                 input2[0][0]                     
                                                                 lambda_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_11 (Lambda)              [(None, 15), (None,  0           input1[0][0]                     
                                                                 input2[0][0]                     
                                                                 lambda_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 30)           0           lambda_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_11[0][1]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 2)            62          concatenate_1[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 112
Trainable params: 112
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```